# I created a table with React and MUI, and implemented Soting, but the sorting is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I implemented a sorting function in my React Table. I want the "Nationality" column to sort in ascending and descending way. But the sorting is not working. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import TableSortLabel from "@mui/material/TableSortLabel";
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import "./table.css";


function createUserData (fullname, email, nationality, city){
    return {fullname, email, nationality, city};
}

const rows= [];

export default function RandomUserTable(){
    const [data, setData]= useState([]);

    const [rowData, setRowData]= useState(rows);
    const [orderDirection, setOrderDirection]= useState("asc");




    useEffect(()=>{
            fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((data) => {
                setData(data);
                console.log(data);
              });
    }, []);

    const sortArray= (arr, orderBy)=> {
        switch (orderBy){
            case "asc":
              default:
                return arr.sort ((a,b)=>
                a.nationality> b.nationality? 1:b.nationality > a.nationality? -1:0
                    );
            case "desc":
                return arr.sort((a, b)=>
                a.nationality < b.nationality ? 1 : b.nationality< a.nationality ? -1 : 0 
                );
        }
    };

    const handleSortRequest = ()=>{
        setRowData(sortArray(rows, orderDirection));
        setOrderDirection(orderDirection === "asc"? "desc":"asc");
    }
   

    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table aria-label="simple table" stickyHeader>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    Fullname                 
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                         E-Mail 
                  
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell onClick={handleSortRequest} align="right">
                <TableSortLabel active={true} direction={orderDirection}>
                    Nationality
                    </TableSortLabel>
                    </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">City</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {data.results?.map((user,index) => (
                <TableRow key={index}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  { (user.name.first)+ " " +(user.name.last)}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{user.email}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{user.nat}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{user.location.city}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sort modify the array directly, you should create a shallow copy of the state and then sort the copy

```js
const sortArray= (arr, orderBy)=> {
        switch (orderBy){
            case "asc":
              default:
                return [...arr].sort ((a,b)=>
                a.nationality> b.nationality? 1:b.nationality > a.nationality? -1:0
                    );
            case "desc":
                return [...arr].sort((a, b)=>
                a.nationality < b.nationality ? 1 : b.nationality< a.nationality ? -1 : 0 
                );
        }
    };
```